# PHP: How to prevent mysql injection with bulk insert by loading data from file

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-injection

So I'm pulling a json file from some location with about 50,000 rows. I'm doing a bulk insert with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/test.txt' INTO TABLE TEST`.

I'm writing all the fields of each tuple into a text file and calling`LOAD DATA INFILE` on it. But the data i'm writing or inserting is not escaped. In php, how can I escape this type of bulk insert? Generally I use prepared statements, but I don't see how you can do it with `LOAD DATA INFILE`. Or is there a better way to do this bulk insert?

EDIT: Request for example text file

I'd just write data in this format in the text file:

```
apple,orange,banana
mango,berry,guava
apricot,nectarine,peaches
```

apple, orange, banana would be a tuple in the table.

Comment: Can you post an example of text.txt?

Comment: Have you tried mysql_real_escape_strings function?

Comment: This is not vulnerable to SQL injections as the data in the file is only interpreted as data and not as code.